# convert a string to a sequence of binary

Tags: python-2.7

i want to convert any char to its binary representation(not a string like my cuurent code does now) it needs to be a sequence of binary numbers 
after that i will take every 16 bits from what i've done and calculate their sum
 *i cant use numpy or any other package
 this is what i got now and it*

```
def checksum(st):
    data  = ' '.join(map(bin,bytearray(st)))
    binar = [data[i:i+16] for i in range(0, len(data), 16)]
    check = 0xffff
    for hex in binar:
        check += int(hex,2)
    return check
```

my current code gets a string (for example:'10100/01') and i want to sum every 16 bits of the string therefor i need to convert the string to binary numbers and then sum every 16 bits together

Comment: I added spaces to your code for readability. My first edit, please don't eat me. Anyhow, why `int` instead of `ord`? Am I missing something?

Comment: ord gets a single char i want to convert a string of two chars (16 bit) to their binary.. ord does not help me.. and my current code is not good now

Comment: my problem is that data contains string of the binary representation and i cant work with it not even to split it to 16 bits every time , because in the second line it counts the chars of 0 and b of the prefix "0b10101"

Comment: I admit that I have no idea what the first two lines in your function are supposed to achieve. It doesn't actually do anything for what you want to do. At least not based on the question, which is "how do i take the sum of a sequence of words created out of a string?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answers your question, assuming I understood it properly. The first two lines of your code don't seem to do what you want to achieve, but maybe you just forgot mentioning something.

Anyhow.

```
def checksum2(st):
    dummy = 0xFFFF
    for count in xrange(0,len(st),2):
        dummy += ord(st[count])+ord(st[count+1])*256
    return dummy
```

This code steps through every second char of your string and adds the value of one char to the value of the next char times 256, which creates a word. Remove the `*256` if you didn't actually want to create a proper 16bit value and instead only wanted to add two 8bit values together. And if you rather need a `big endian`, instead of `little endian`, then just move the `*256` the the other `ord()`.